# How to aggregate and merge one column by a second column in r

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

In my current research I encounter this particular problem surprisingly often. Say I have a data frame with total consumption in all US states. I want to use county population (which I have) to estimate consumption by county (which I don't have). Population data would normally be arranged in a long format with columns representing county, state and population respectivly. If the consumption data is called `cons` and the population data frame is called `pop`, my usual algorithm to solve the problem would be something like this:

```
#data
pop <- as.data.frame(rnorm(12)+4)
pop$county <- letters[10:21]
pop$state <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C","C","C")
colnames(pop)[1] <- "pop"
cons <- as.data.frame(c(10^5, 4*10^4, 8*10^4))
colnames(cons) <- "cons"
cons$state <- c("A", "B", "C")


agg_pop <- aggregate(list(pop_state = pop$pop), by = list(state = pop$state), FUN = sum, na.rm = T) # aggregating population by state
pop <- merge(pop, agg_pop, by = "state") # Merging the state population with the county population data
pop$share <- pop$pop/pop$pop_state # Calculating each county's share of state population
pop <- merge(pop, cons, by = "state") # Merging consumption data onto population data
pop$estimated_cons <- pop$cons * pop$share # multiplying county's share of state population with state consumption
```

Can anyone think of an easier way to do this, using only one or maybe two functions?

Comment: Hello! Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: can you share a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: @grouah I have tried to add an example with mock data

Comment: Hello @pkpkPPkafa, was my answer useful? if so, don"t hesitate to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
pop %>% 
  left_join(cons) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(share_cons=cons*(pop/sum(pop)))

Joining, by = "state"
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   state [3]
     pop county state   cons share_cons
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1  3.63 j      A     100000     23226.
 2  4.09 k      A     100000     26157.
 3  3.71 l      A     100000     23763.
 4  4.20 m      A     100000     26854.
 5  5.32 n      B      40000     14913.
 6  3.59 o      B      40000     10062.
 7  5.36 p      B      40000     15026.
 8  4.06 q      C      80000     16029.
 9  1.77 r      C      80000      6985.
10  4.45 s      C      80000     17568.
11  5.38 t      C      80000     21228.
12  4.61 u      C      80000     18190.
```